# Data is not populated in data table with array objects, getting blank screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Data is not populated in data table with array objects, getting blank screen. Tried with below code, any issue pls suggest

```
$('#example3').DataTable( {
        data:storedJsonData,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "salary" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" }
        ]
    } );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tm31j7w/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is not populated because  columns header  is case sensitive  and must equal to given data.

I fix your data and columns header. Now it's work and show your data on DataTable.

```js
var storedJsonData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "Age": "63",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "extn": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "def",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "Age": "63",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "extn": "2"
  }
];

$('#example3').DataTable({
  data: storedJsonData,
  "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    },
    {
      "data": "name"
    },
    {
      "data": "position"
    },
    {
      "data": "salary"
    },
    {
      "data": "start_date"
    },
    {
      "data": "office"
    },
    {
      "data": "extn"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example3" class="display" style="width:100%">

</table>
```